# JSF 2.1 + RichFaces 4 rich:dataScroller

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have the following datascroller

```
            <rich:dataScroller for="productsList" id="scroller" maxPages="10">
                     <f:facet name="next">
                        <h:outputText value="fist page" />
                     </f:facet>
                     <f:facet name="previous">
                        <h:outputText value="last page" />
                     </f:facet>
                </rich:dataScroller>
```

I would like to remove firstPage (>>>>) and lastPage (<<<<) buttons. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fastControls="hide" boundaryControls="hide"` should do it :)